# How do you activate Text Editor in v2.78?

Tags: text-editor

How can I activate the text field in the Text Editor? Video tutorials show more options than I see on my Text Editor ( v2.78 ).
[image: Text Editor]

Comment: Have you selected/added a text block to edit? What kind of options are you referring to?

Comment: I missed the bottom part of the text editor.  It only shows a find box box.

Comment: There should be more buttons and fields on the bottom strip such as "New File" and "Run script". No I didn't adda text block. That sounds like the solution. Thank you.

Comment: How do you add a Text block?

Comment: There should be a *plus* button that says *New*.

Comment: No plus button. Just a Find Box. Can't paste a picture of the bottom menu strip that shows the find box.

Comment: Can you screenshot it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73633/discussion-between-barrie-and-omar-ahmad).

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I was in Sensei format, a plugin created by the person who created Zbrush. It Changes the interface to something more appealing to nubies like me. I won't use it again because It makes it difficult to follow Tutorials. Text edit works as expected when Sensei is disabled.

Comment: What is 'Sensei format'? This doesn't sound like something Blender has by default.

Comment: Sensei Format is a plugin created by the person who created Zbrush. It Changes the interface to something more appealing to nubies like me. I won't use it again because It makes it difficult to follow Tutorials.

Comment: It's a really wierd add-on that changes the UI lol. I didn't know it was made by pixologic. Interesting!